# View PC screen on Android

Tags: android

I am working on project and I need to view the PC screen on the Android phone or tablet and controlling the Android by the PC ?

The important thing now to view the screen of PC on Android .. Can anyone help ? :)

Comment: find VNC protocol and how is it done. Then, you may want use existing code instead reinventig the wheel.

Comment: I agree with @Pihhan. look at the VNC client implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement Socket connection and have to create a local server that can send the screen to you phone as image.
in java awt there is a way that you can capture the screen of you pc. so may be some googleing can help you

Answer (score 1):

your question is unclear. i get two scenarios in mind

1. View and control your **PC from Android**:You can use Teamviewer (install it both on pc and android), or you can use various vnc clients available.
2. View and control your **Android from PC**:you can use Android screencast (code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/   requires adb)

Comment: The first scenario which I mean.

Comment: But I don`t want to use a program like teamviewer in my App .. The desktop sharing function I want to build is a part of the whole App